# how to display full Url in web browser control properly in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I can display the Url in the searchbar. However, it picks up javascript and other loading processes as URL and displays them and doesn't display a conventional Url (e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions) that we would see in any common browser. So if I search http://www.stackoverflow.com, I get https://ssum-sec.casalemedia.com/usermatch?s=183712&cb=https://engine.adzerk.net/udb/22/sync/i.gif?partnerId=1&userId=. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {

            player.SoundLocation = "safepage.wav";
                player.Play();


            if (SearchBar.Text != e.Url.ToString())   //Displays the full Webpage address within the textbox
            {
                SearchBar.Text = e.Url.ToString();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation events of web browser control will raise for iframes of the page too. So in this case, what you are getting as result is address of an iframe in the page.

You can use `webBrowser1.Url.ToString()` instead of `e.Url.ToString()`.

**Note:** As far as I know, there should not be an iframe in stackoverflow questions page, so itt seems your browser has been infected.

Comment: its still in development through debug mode and to my knowledge hasn't been infected.

Comment: I didn't say your application is infected, but probably the browser is.

Comment: In fact the main point of the answer for this site is the first part: *Navigation events of web browser control will raise for iframes of the page too. So in this case, what you are getting as result is address of an iframe in the page.* But while your question in comments is off-topic here, yes there is solutions, for example: [How do you get rid of Casalemedia, Zedo Tribal popups?](https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/how-do-you-get-rid-of-casalemedia-zedo-tribal-popups-293332/) or using an anti-virus, anti-spyware and so on.

Comment: there is no casalemedia on my system, as firstly the development is in a virtual machine and secondly according to that link, there is no process of casalemedia in the task manager. Furthermore, I have had avast antivirus on my main system (MacBook) since I purchased it .

Comment: No problem, just keep it in mind as a warning and now use `webBrowser1.Url.ToString()` instead of `e.Url.ToString()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In the _Navigated event, you can use the WebBrowser.Url property. It will get updated each time but not for the redirects like for those tracking/ad scripts.